# Filtered colimits commute with finite limits in category $\textbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a filtered category and $\mathcal{D}$ a finite category. Consider a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\textbf{Ab}$. I want to show that
$$\text{co}\!\lim_C\lim_D F(C,D)\cong\lim_D\text{co}\!\lim_C F(C,D).\tag{1}$$

Let $U:\textbf{Ab}\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor. Then $U\circ F:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$. Thus
$$\text{co}\!\lim_C\lim_D U(F(C,D))\cong\lim_D\text{co}\!\lim_C U(F(C,D)).\tag{2}$$
How can I use (2) along with the fact that $U$ reflects and preserves filtered colimits in order to conclude (1)? What are the steps involved in such an argument? (E.g. are there "algebraic" manipulations that take us from (2) to (1)?)

**Edit:**

Can I just use the fact that $U$ reflects isomorphisms?

Comment: You can use the fact that $U$ preserves filtered colimits and finite limits and reflects isomorphisms to reduce the claim to  $\mathbf{Set}$. This argument works for many categories other than $\mathbf{Ab}$.